# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'getV' of undefined

Tags: javascript, function, this

I have this function in javascript:

```
function test(obj,arg1,arg2) {
   ...
   ...
   this.getV=function() {
      var x=2;
      return x; 
   }
}
```

How can i resolve this problem ?

Comment: Can you supply more of the code? Can you explain what `this` should be referring to (or what you think it should refer to)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function test(obj,arg1,arg2) {
   ...
   ...
   this.getV = function() { // getV() is wrong you are declaring function
      var x = 2;
      return x; 
   }
}
var testObj = new test();
testObj.getV(); // return 2
```

Answer (score 0):

This Line:
`this.getV()=function(){ var x=2; return x; }`

causes the Error. **getV()** is undefined! you have to define it like that:

```
this.getV = function(){ var x=2; return x; }
```